# Blender 2.8 Beta wouldn't load old 2.79 Key Configuration

Tags: customization

Blender 2.8 Beta wouldn't import 2.79 Key Configuration

Is this a bug or a feature?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keymaps and input settings changed significantly between 2.7# and 2.8 to the point where it is not trivial to make them compatible.

For this reason, importing old keymaps has been intentionally disabled.

Comment: But before, Blender offered an emulation of 3DS Max keyboard shortcuts for easier transition. Is this going to be available again?

Comment: Chances are, more keymap  templates are going to be added later. I think the developers are busy with bugs at the moment.