# Conversion chart for blender 2.8

Tags: interface

Does anybody know if there is a conversion chart showing where stuff was and where it is now on the user interface, please?
I have taken ages to learn Blender 2.7 and now I have to learn where everything is again. At the moment I'm about ready to forget 2.8 and just stick with 2.79.

Dave

Comment: What specifically do you want to know? Blender has a very wide range of applications it can be used for and there were really a lot of changes from 2.79 to 2.80. Hundreds of changes were made and hundreds of new features were added. I think the documentation would be the closest thing to what you are asking for and it is not finished yet as Blender 2.80 is not yet released. You can get some general info here: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80 but I don't think you can have just a simple chart to summarize everything that would make much sense.

Comment: Most things that could be converted are about where they were. Some things are missing and there are some new things, cannot be converted. If you are not willing to learn new things just keep using 2.79, simple.

Comment: Martin, at the moment, I want to know where the "add background images" is now,  and how to change the camera clip distance. I have changed the view clip distance, but cannot find the camera clip distance for rendering.

Comment: Jaroslav, I asked for help not patronising.

Comment: Jaroslav is not being patronizing, 2.8 is still a work in progress, it [changed considerably and will change further in the future](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139817/will-importing-user-preferences-from-version-2-79b-to-2-80-work-and-is-it-a-good). The manual and release notes will eventually document what changed. In the meantime it is best to search for what specific things you are missing, they most likely have already been answered before like [Background Images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110532/cannot-find-background-images-feature-in-blender-2-8)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Jaroslav Jerryno Novotny , I apologise, I was tired and what I said was out of order.