# Is it possible to automatically inherit/import custom shortcut mappings from an older Blender version to a newer?

Tags: shortcut, quick-favorites

I'm about to start experimenting with Blender 2.81; unfortunately, doing so means all of my custom Quick Favorites and Shortcuts (and other interface changes, e.g. select with RMB) have been lost.

Is there any convenient functionality for importing/inheriting Quick Favorites, Shortcuts, & other custom interface settings from Blender 2.80 to 2.81, so that I don't have to manually customize settings one-by-one?

Comment: You can import/export keymaps, however when you load the old keymap into the new version you'd potentially lose new shortcuts for new tools.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139817/will-importing-user-preferences-from-version-2-79b-to-2-80-work-and-is-it-a-good/139878#139878

Comment: Thanks, that's somewhat helpful. I think the situation you were addressing with your other, linked answer may be somewhat different from what I have in mind though, Duarte; my goal with imports isn't to avoid adopting new shortcuts etc, but to carry over my established list of 2.80 Quick Favorites, as well as other Shortcuts that I setup because there did not seem to be an existing shortcut for them, not because I wished to override the default shortcuts.

Also, I'm hoping that, with the gap between 2.80 and 2.81 being smaller than between 2.79 and 2.80, importing might be less destructive?