# File Type that keeps Armature , UV , weight ,textures

Tags: texturing, uv, rigging, armature, weight-painting

I use older version of Blender daily , it's good that Blender keeps evolving but newer versions keep changing shortcuts , names , UI and more and it's ruining my workflow. I do not have time to spend changing all of my habits every time Blender have an update.

So I am looking for a type of file that keeps the armature, weights, UVs, texture of a rigged model that can be exported from new blenders to older Blenders.

I tried fbx , xps , dae and what not , but it never works for the image texture (and I do not have the time to manually do it on hundred of files).

What kind of file type do I need to use?

Comment: That file format is .blend, nothing else you use will preserve more data than the actual native format. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Blender doesn't change that much that often, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/139878/19307

Comment: I just found an addon ( free ) that does the trick , it will save me a lot of time 