# Is there a way to get all shortcuts of 2.79 back?

Tags: shortcut

I have a lot of trouble transitioning from 2.79 to 2.8 because I was so used to hotkeys in older versions. Is there a way I can recover all 2.79 shortcuts for blender 2.8x? I mean  all, really...

Things like:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> for *rendered mode*
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> in *edit mode* for switching between *vertex*, *edge* and *face selection*
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> for *camera fly mode*
- <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> for searching
- ...

**Q:** How can I recover all 2.79 hotkeys?

Comment: What may have been your problem is that you had too many custom hotkeys. You can go to the Blender preferences, and adjust the input hotkeys for individual functions if you like.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124354/blender-2-8-beta-wouldnt-load-old-2-79-key-configuration/124370#124370 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139817/will-importing-user-preferences-from-version-2-79b-to-2-80-work-and-is-it-a-good/139878#139878

Answer (score 2):

While I made the same switch as you and felt like I had to relearn blender, I am now very comfortable with the new controls, and they are much more intuitive. However, if you do want to stay with they 2.79 controls, here’s how you do it:

Go to preferences>keymap. Next in the drop-down bar at the top that currently says blender, click on that and change the selection to “Blender 27X”. This should give you all the shortcuts from 2.79. Hope this helps!

Comment: First I also thought the keymap of 2.8  could be better because I used blender for a long time, but the 2.8 keymap is much better, And all new tutorials are made the the new keymap....